# Empty Strings: Why or when is '' equal to ' '?

Tags: sql-server-2008, empty-string

Who can explain why

```
select case when '' = ' ' then 1 else 0 end, LEN(''), LEN(' '), DATALENGTH(''), DATALENGTH(' ');
```

yields

```
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           0           0           0           1
```

The funny consequence of this is that in

```
create table test ( val varchar(10) );
insert into test values( '' );
update test set val = ' ' where val = '';
```

the update will indeed replace the empty string by a blank, but the where clause keeps to be true and repeated executions of the update statement tell

```
(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Trailing blanks explained](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626):

> SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2,
>   , General rules #3) on how to compare strings
>   with spaces. The ANSI standard requires padding for the character
>   strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before
>   comparing them. The padding directly affects the semantics of WHERE
>   and HAVING clause predicates and other Transact-SQL string
>   comparisons. For example, Transact-SQL considers the strings 'abc' and
>   'abc ' to be equivalent for most comparison operations.
>
> The only exception to this rule is the LIKE predicate. When the right
>   side of a LIKE predicate expression features a value with a trailing
>   space, SQL Server does not pad the two values to the same length
>   before the comparison occurs. Because the purpose of the LIKE
>   predicate, by definition, is to facilitate pattern searches rather
>   than simple string equality tests, this does not violate the section
>   of the ANSI SQL-92 specification mentioned earlier.

Here's a well known example of all the cases mentioned above:

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @b varchar(10)

SET @a = '1'
SET @b = '1 ' --with trailing blank

SELECT 1
WHERE 
    @a = @b 
AND @a NOT LIKE @b
AND @b LIKE @a
```

Here's some more detail about [trailing blanks and the `LIKE` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).