# Isn't a tab (char(9) ) whitespace in the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2, , General rules #3)?

Tags: sql-server

If there is any sane reason to ignore trailing blanks in varchar comparisons, why doesn't that apply to tab-characters too ?

On SQL Server I get

```
SELECT
    case when '' = ' ' then 'true' else 'false' end, 
    case when '' = CHAR(9) then 'true' else 'false' end
```

yields

```
---- -----
true false
```

Is this a problem of the ANSI specification or a problem of the SQL Server implementation?

**Edit:**

I do not have access to the text of the specification. I only see it mentioned in this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9457/136). I can't tell if it addresses only blanks or if it refers to whitespace in some vague sense.

Comment: You have the ANSI 92 text in my answer in case you didn't see. I quote it often...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same code above on MySQL 5.5 gives the same result

Tab isn't "space", it is a character.
The same applies to hard/non-breaking space (char(160) in "normal" collations)

The [ANSI-92 standard states in 8.2. item 3.a](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)

> If the length in characters of X is not equal to the length
>                 in characters of Y, then the shorter string is effectively
>                 replaced, for the purposes of comparison, with a copy of
>                 itself that has been extended to the length of the longer
>                 string by concatenation on the right of one or more pad char-
>                 acters, where the pad character is chosen based on CS. If
>                 CS has the NO PAD attribute, then the pad character is an
>                 implementation-dependent character different from any char-
>                 acter in the character set of X and Y that collates less
>                 than any string under CS. Otherwise, the pad character is a `<space>`.

CS is "collating sequence". I'll assume no collation uses tab or non-breaking spaces as padding characters. So space it is...

Note that LIKE is section 8.5 (I mention this because of your [previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9456/empty-strings-why-or-when-is-equal-to))